# Haskell Relations Error - Syntax error in declaration (unexpected `;', possibly due to bad layout)

Tags: haskell, syntax-error

I'm fairly new to Haskell and I don't fully understand this error, when I load the file hugs prints out the following "Syntax error in declaration (unexpected `;', possibly due to bad layout)" at the line "check s1 s2 ((x,y):xs)". I find this confusing as there isn't a ";" in the code. If someone could explain why this is happening and how I can fix it I would be very grateful. Bellow is my code.

```
type Owned = String  
type Owner = String  
type Fact = (Owned,Owner)

database = [(String, String)]  
database = [("c4","c5"),("c1","c2"), ("c2", "c3"), ("c3","c4")]

owns :: Owner -> Owned -> Bool

owns s1 s2  
      | check s1 s2 database = true  
      | otherwise false

check s1 s2 ((x,y):xs)  
     | s1==x && y==s2 = true  
     | s1==x && y==s2 = (check y s2 database)  
     | otherwise false
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, there are ; in the transformed source code. The Haskell Report contains a detailed explanation about how the source code is transformed with the layout rules. One should read them once, it's quite intuitive.

Though such errors are indeed confusing for a newcomer, the following rules of thumb apply:

- If the compiler complains about ';' you have a syntax error in the last nonempty line *before* the line reported.
- More often than not, the error comes about due to layout (as indeed the compiler suggested). Nevertheless, there are other cases as your example shows: the compiler desperately looks for a '=' in the second guard of function `owns` and when he finds the semicolon just before `check` he knows there is something wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, I had to alter some parts of my code but it now works perfectly thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing an `=` in the `otherwise` branches:

```
type Owned = String  
type Owner = String  
type Fact = (Owned,Owner)

database = [(String, String)]  
database = [("c4","c5"),("c1","c2"), ("c2", "c3"), ("c3","c4")]

owns :: Owner -> Owned -> Bool

owns s1 s2  
      | check s1 s2 database = true  
      | otherwise = false

check s1 s2 ((x,y):xs)  
     | s1==x && y==s2 = true  
     | s1==x && y==s2 = (check y s2 database)  
     | otherwise = false
```